# C++ Program Weird int

Tags: c++, cout

i'm running a C++ program that classifies data into two different categories using a threshold to distinguish between them. But It wasn't working when i cout the int that holds the data it showed this -1.#IND. Has any one ever seen that??And if they have can you tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Post the code. Without it how can anyone help you?

Comment: are you sure you're using integers, and not floating point types ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-1.#IND` indicates a negative indefinite NaN, which is the result of an invalid floating point operation (eg. take the square root of a negative number).

So, while your question mentions integers, you seem to be using floating point types instead. And you seem to have performed an invalid operation.